# How to run a python script which imports 2 other python scripts that have to be run using different versions of python

Tags: python, bash

I have two scripts a.py and b.py.

a.py runs with python3 and b.py runs with python2.7.

Now I want to import these two scripts in a new script called c.py and run c.py. How exactly should I accomplish this. How should i tell bash which versions to use for which script. My default linux python version is 2.7. Thnaks for your help.

Comment: What is 2.7 specific about `b.py`? Can it be ported to Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to import `a.py` and `b.py` into `c.py`, you must choose *one* Python version for `c.py`. This will probably have to be Python 3. So you have to port `b.py` to Python 3.

This has nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: b.py is specific to python2.7. I import a few modules in b.py that work only with 2.7. So what I was attempting to do is to import b.py and a.py into c.py and run c.py using 2.7 and using the shebang line #!/usr/bin/python3 in a.py script. But that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Of course this does not work. If `a.py` is Python 3, the *whole* code must be Python 3. Port your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot practically do that i.e by calling both the files in another file as the other two files a.py and b.py are two different versions of Python.

Syntax in both 2.7.x and 3.4.x are quite different this is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

you can modify `a.py` and/or `b.py` so it work in python 2 or 3 regardless by adding a [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) import, of course you can't use python 3 exclusive stuff like function annotation or `yield from`

like this

```
from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import, unicode_literals
#everyting else
```

or just import the features that are different between version that you need like `print_function` or `division`

With this you can open a.py in python 2 without problem.

Also you must have installed all the same packages in both version in case that you import something else

you can also add this to `a.py`

```
try: #python 2
    from itertools import ifilter as filter, imap as map, izip as zip
except ImportError:
    #python 3
    pass

try: #python 2
    range = xrange
except NameError:
    #python 3
    pass
```

if you use any of those so they work the same in both python 3 and 2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run them sequentially:

```
python2.7 a.py && python3.4 b.py
```

If you want to run them simultaneously:

```
python2.7 a.py & python3.4 b.py
```

(Assuming that `a.py` is a python 2.7 script and `b.py` a python 3.4 one)

And if you want a new script you could try something like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("python2.7 a.py && python3.4 b.py")
```

Comment: "Now I want to import these two scripts in a new script called c.py and run c.py"

Comment: @Tichodroma I've added this to my answer, have a look

Comment: There is still not Python import in your answer.

Comment: @Tichodroma not in a literal sense, but afaic that's the only way to call two existent scripts that require different python versions without having to refactor one of them.

Comment: But calling is not the same as importing. Your answer probably does not what the question asks for.

Comment: @Tichodroma The original question is contradictory anyway, it first asks for how to import python scripts and then for "How should i tell bash which versions to use for which script.". I do answer this last question..